# Nested iteration in thymeleaf not working properly

Tags: html, spring-boot, nested, iterator, thymeleaf

I am trying to get build a seat selection view for a cinema hall. I managed to iterate the objects from Arraylist but row_iterator gets stuck at 0 in line 3, where i set top position `<i>(top: '+(row_iterator.index*20)+'px')</i>`.

On lines 2 and 6 the iterator works. Any help appreciated

HTML:

```
<th:block class="hall__row" th:each="row, row_iterator: ${theater.getRows()}">
    <div class="hall__places-row _left" th:attr="data-row=${row.getId()}" th:attrappend="style=${'top: '+(row_iterator.index*20)+'px'}"> </div>
    <div class="hall__places-item is-free" th:each="seat, seat_iterator : ${row.getSeats()}" th:attr="data-row=${row.getId()}" data-column="1" data-price-id="1" data-pos-x="1" data-pos-y="12" data-state="free" data-price="40" data-place-size="20" th:attrappend="style=${'left: '+((seat_iterator.index+1)*20)+'px;'+'top: '+(row_iterator.index*20)+'px'}">
        <div class="hall__places-chair" th:attr="data-title=${movie.getPrice()}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hall__places-row _right" th:attr="data-row=${row.getId()}" th:attrappend="style=${'top: '+(row_iterator.index*20)+'px'}"> </div>
</th:block>
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: i am not getting any errors. just the value of row_iterator.index is always 0

Comment: Not sure if  I understand what you are trying to do or not. try replace with `th:each=" row,row_iterator: ${#numbers.sequence(0, theater.getRows()}"`

Comment: i have an object Theater, which contains an Arraylist of Row objects, and Row contain an Arraylist of Seat. I am iterating through Theater, getting every Row from it, and from every Row i get Seats. Then i need to position the rows vertically, by setting their position from top with top: '+(row_iterator.index*20)+'px'  and i am positioning every seat by setting their position from left with left: '+((seat_iterator.index+1)*20). This way seats are 20 px apart and rows aswell.

Comment: The problem i have is that I get all the seats at same position from top , because row_iterator.index from th:attrappend="style=${'left: '+((seat_iterator.index+1)*20)+'px;'+'top: '+(row_iterator.index*20)+'px'} always has value 0.